# What's the difference between login as user and changing users using su through root?

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

When you have a server of some sort you can access it through, e.g., `ssh user1@ip` and you can also do `ssh root@ip` to go to your root user with su priveleges and then go to `su user1`. In my thinking both those ways should lead me to the same user environment(in this case, "user1"), but in my actual experience it does not, cause in `ssh user1@ip` there's things installed that in `su user1` there isn't.

Why is that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SSH starts a login shell. `su`, by default does not.

In particular, this means that the `~/.profile` (or similar file) for that user is not sourced. So changes made in `~/.profile` won't take effect. It might also be the case that:

- even if you start a login shell, different changes were made in root's `~/.profile`, which might pollute the user's environment.

  - `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*` may apply settings differently for different users (not by default, though)
- there might be different settings for different users in SSH configuration.
- PAM configuration is different. For example, `/etc/pam.d/ssh` has:

  ```
  session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
  ```

  whereas `/etc/pam.d/su` has:

  ```
  session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
  ```

  This means SSH loads `~/.pam_environment`, but `su` doesn't. This is a big one, since `~/.pam_environment` is the shell-independent place for environment variables, and it is applied if you login from the GUI, the TTY or SSH.

To start a login shell, run either of:

```
su - <username>
sudo -iu <username>
```

Example:

```
# su muru -c 'sh -c "echo $HOME $PATH"'
/home/muru /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
# su - muru -c 'sh -c "echo $HOME $PATH"'
/home/muru /home/muru/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
# sudo -iu muru sh -c 'echo $HOME $PATH'
/home/muru /home/muru/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# sudo -u muru sh -c 'echo $HOME $PATH'
/root /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# ssh muru@localhost 'echo $HOME $PATH'
/home/muru /home/muru/devel/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Even with SSH, if you run a command instead of starting a shell, a login shell won't be run (note the absence of `~/bin` in the SSH test, which is present in `su -` and `sudo -i`). To get the true result, I will run my shell as a login shell:

```
# ssh muru@localhost '$SHELL -ilc "echo \$HOME \$PATH"'
/home/muru /home/muru/bin:/home/muru/devel/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

---

This is also why `sudo su` and `sudo -s` are crappy ways of getting a root shell. Both these ways are polluted by the environment.

---

Related:

- [Unix & Linux: su vs sudo -s vs sudo -i vs sudo bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35342/70524)

Comment: Seems i should be awake before taking on questions :) your answer is wonderful and mine missed to target the proper answer. Well done +1

Answer (score -1):

By and large it's mainly a strategic difference.

If you're logged in as a super user, you can change anything all the time ... ie - there's no protection against catastrophic mistakes, you'd have to temporarily change to some other user for safety.

Whereas: if you're logged in with limited privileges, you avoid some risk of catastrophic mistakes, because you have to intentionally shift to su root for temporary access to that power, but now you have the default fall-back position to a safe user.

The difference is therefore really strategic, not technical.

Comment: The question wasn't exactly the difference of root user from others users. It was the difference between accessing a server user directly through ssh and accessing it through su already inside the root user. 

Anyway, I agree with what you said too haha thanks

Comment: Ah ok, sorry ... I was actually wondering why everyone was going into technical detail, I guess I misread your intention.